# ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

Estou aprendendo um pouco de mysql e decidi faer um sisteminha de mercado, eu tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cliente(cliente_cpf BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY 
KEY,cliente_nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,cliente_sexo BIT NOT 
NULL,cliente_nascimento DATE NOT NULL,cliente_email 
VARCHAR(50),cliente_telefone BIGINT,cliente_celular BIGINT);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS produto(produto_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY 
KEY,produto_nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,produto_preco FLOAT(5,2) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item_pedido(item_pedido_id INT NOT 
NULL,item_pedido_produto_id INT NOT NULL,item_pedido_produto_quantidade 
TINYINT NOT NULL,FOREIGN KEY(item_pedido_produto_id) references 
produto(produto_id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pedido(pedido_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
PRIMARY KEY,pedido_cliente_cpf BIGINT NOT NULL,pedido_item_pedido_id INT NOT 
NULL DEFAULT 0,pedido_data_compra TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),pedido_valor_total FLOAT(6,2),FOREIGN KEY 
(pedido_item_pedido_id) REFERENCES item_pedido(item_pedido_id),FOREIGN KEY 
(pedido_cliente_cpf) REFERENCES cliente(cliente_cpf));
```

Estou com um problema na tabla pedido com relação a adicionar a definir pedido_item_pedido_id na tabela pedido, todo o resto funciona certinho e se eu nao adicionar essa foreign key a tabela pedido tambem funciona, o erro é ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint, eu pesquisei e eu não vi o porque dar esse erro, alguem consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

#### Motivo do erro:

Você precisa "indexar" o `item_pedido_id` da tabela `item_pedido`.

---

#### Por quê?

> A chave estrangeira requer referência a uma chave primária e/ou única.

---

#### Resolução:

Coloque `item_pedido_id` da tabela `item_pedido` como `UNIQUE` e/ou `PRIMARY KEY`.

---

#### Exemplo em seu script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item_pedido(
      item_pedido_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
      item_pedido_produto_id INT NOT NULL,
      item_pedido_produto_quantidade TINYINT NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY(item_pedido_produto_id) references produto(produto_id)
);
```

Comment: Eu cheguei a pensar nisso mas como eu preciso que um valor se repita varias vezes em item_pedido_id na tabela item_pedido eu nao fiz isso, nesse caso essa seria a unica forma de resolução?

Comment: Sim. Não tem lógica você fazer uma referência em outra tabela se ela te retornar mais de 1 registro. A solução seria alterar a estrutura das tabelas pelo visto. Se quiser uma ajuda, abra outra pergunta, mostrando como está a estrutura do seu banco, o seu "problema" com isso, e possíveis soluções. Com certeza o pessoal irá te ajudar.