# Foreign key para tabelas diferentes (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, chave-estrangeira

Na hora de executar a query da erro informando que não é possível criar as foreign keys, procurei na documentação e não entendi direito se esse código é possível ou não.

```
create table autor(
    cod_autor integer,
    nome varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    nascimento date NOT NULL,
    primary key(cod_autor)
);

create table editora(
    cod_editora int,
    razao text,
    endereco varchar(50),
    cnpj int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    cidade varchar(40),
    primary key(cod_editora)
);


create table livro(
    titulo varchar (100),
    cd_autor integer NOT NULL,
    cd_editora integer,
    valor float NOT NULL,
    publicacao DATE not null,
    volume INTEGER NOT NULL,
    primary key (titulo,cd_autor),
    foreign key(cd_autor) references autor(cd_autor) ON UPDATE SET NULL  ON DELETE SET NULL,
    foreign key (cd_editora) references autor(cd_autor) ON UPDATE SET NULL ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Erro :

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Você tem vários erros:***

- Precisa de um campo PK em `livro`
- Está faltando o tamanho em `razao text,`
- Está fazendo **referências erradas das chaves estrangeiras** ("foreign key").

---

#### Corrigindo

**1 - Adicionei mais um campo para ser chave primária:**

```
create table livro(
    livro_id int,
```

**2 - Coluna `razao`:**

```
razao text(N),
```

N = Caracteres a serem exibidos na coluna.

**3 - Chaves estrangeiras:**

```
foreign key(cd_autor) references autor(cod_autor),
foreign key (cd_editora) references editora(cod_editora) ON UPDATE SET NULL ON DELETE SET NULL
```

---

#### Detalhando

**Na criação do campo `razao`:**

Falta por o tamanho. Exemplo: `text(30)`.

**Na primeira chave estrangeira:**

Em `foreign key(cd_autor)` você está dizendo que a coluna `cd_autor` da tabela `livro` será a chave estrangeira.

E em `references autor(cod_autor)` você está fazendo referência a tabela `autor` e a coluna que irá referenciar, será o `cod_autor` (que a chave primária)

**Na segunda declaração:**

Em `foreign key(cd_editora)` você está dizendo que a coluna `cd_editora` da tabela `livro` será a chave estrangeira.

E em `references autor(cod_editora)` você está fazendo referência a tabela `editora` e a coluna que irá referenciar, será o `cod_editora` (que a chave primária)

Além disso, você não pode definir `ON UPDATE SET NULL  ON DELETE SET NULL` se você exige que a coluna `cd_autor` da tabela `livro` não seja `NULL`: `cd_autor integer NOT NULL,`

**Então ou você tira essas condições, ou não define a coluna como `NOT NULL`.**

---

#### Importante

> A chave estrangeira requer referência a uma chave primária e/ou única (`PRIMARY KEY` e/ou `UNIQUE`).

[Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/313599/92908)

---

Veja o exemplo do seu script funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e053d0).

Comment: Quanto a referencia, foi uma edição errada minha na pergunta antes de publicar, o erro foi exatamente no `ON UPDATE` e `ON DELETE`. A tabela `livro` possui PK: `primary key (titulo,cd_autor),`

Comment: @pic Também aí. Caso não entender algo na resposta, pode perguntar! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Estava errada a variável a que fazias referência. Seria 'cod_autor'.

```
 foreign key(cd_autor) references autor(cod_autor) ON UPDATE SET NULL  ON DELETE SET NULL,
 foreign key (cd_editora) references autor(cod_autor) ON UPDATE SET NULL ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Quanto à segunda foreign key não será:

```
foreign key (cd_editora) references editora(cod_editora) ON UPDATE SET NULL ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Comment: como eu comentei na outra resposta a referencia n era um problema, foi apenas um equivoco na hora de postar a pergunta